# Infinite children created inside object when using a const instead of the object expression itself

Tags: javascript

I have a data array that consists of objects (transactions) with a timestamp inside of them under the key `start`, I needed to create an object that helps me visualize in periods of time (year, month, date) how many transactions where made for each of those time periods (There's actually more data in the original code that I need to extract for each transaction, this is a very simplified version to save your time that only counts the transactions). This is the data array:

```
const data =[
  {
    "start": "2020-09-07T22:27:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-09-08T12:27:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-09-08T22:27:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-11-08T22:27:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2019-11-08T22:27:24.000Z"
  }
]
```

Each object represents a transaction. What I needed was to have an object that tells me the transaction count for each year, for each month and for each day. This is my first soultion:

```
const getAllData = (transactions) =>{
    //Emtpy array to store everything
    let processedTransactions ={};
    //Iterate trough every transaaction
    transactions.forEach( ({start}) =>{
        //Get the day, month and year
        const startDate = new Date(start);
        const day = startDate.getDate();
        const month = startDate.getMonth();
        const year = startDate.getFullYear();
        const yearDiff = new Date().getFullYear() - year;
        //Validate if the timestamp is valid and if its from the last 3 years
        if( !Number.isNaN(day)  && !Number.isNaN(month) && !Number.isNaN(year) && yearDiff<3){
            //Check if the year exists and if not create the data for it
            processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || {count : 0};
            //Acumulate data for that year
            processedTransactions[year].count++;

            //Check if the month exists and if not create the data for it
            processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || {count : 0};
            //Acumulate data for that month
            processedTransactions[year][month].count++;

            //Check if the day exists and if not create the data for it
            processedTransactions[year][month][day] = processedTransactions[year][month][day] || {count : 0};
            //Acumulate data for that day
            processedTransactions[year][month][day].count++; 

        }  
    });
    return processedTransactions;
}
```

It works well and I ended up with this object:

```
{
   "2019":{
      "10":{
         "8":{
            "count":1
         },
         "count":1
      },
      "count":1
   },
   "2020":{
      "8":{
         "7":{
            "count":1
         },
         "8":{
            "count":2
         },
         "count":3
      },
      "10":{
         "8":{
            "count":1
         },
         "count":1
      },
      "count":4
   }
}
```

This way if I can know how many transactions where made in 2019 using `processedTransactions.2019.count` or how many transactions where made in September 8th, 2020 using `processedTransactions.2020.8.8.count` so I can use the data in a chart.

Later I decided to make the code easier to read and declared this object:

```
const defaultData = {count : 0};
```

To change these lines of code:

```
processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || {count : 0};
...
processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || {count : 0};
...
processedTransactions[year][month][day] = processedTransactions[year][month][day] || {count : 0};
```

Into:

```
processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || defaultData;
...
processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || defaultData;
...
processedTransactions[year][month][day] = processedTransactions[year][month][day] || defaultData;
```

So the function ended up like this:

```
const getAllDataII = (transactions) =>{
    //Emtpy array to store everything
    let processedTransactions ={};
    const defaultData = {count : 0};
    //Iterate trough every transaaction
    transactions.forEach( ({start}) =>{
        //Get the day, month and year
        const startDate = new Date(start);
        const day = startDate.getDate();
        const month = startDate.getMonth();
        const year = startDate.getFullYear();
        const yearDiff = new Date().getFullYear() - year;
        //Validate if the timestamp is valid and if its from the last 3 years
        if( !Number.isNaN(day)  && !Number.isNaN(month) && !Number.isNaN(year) && yearDiff<3){
            //Check if the year exists and if not create the data for it
            processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || defaultData;
            //Acumulate data for that year
            processedTransactions[year].count++;

            //Check if the month exists and if not create the data for it
            processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || defaultData;
            //Acumulate data for that month
            processedTransactions[year][month].count++;

            //Check if the day exists and if not create the data for it
            processedTransactions[year][month][day] = processedTransactions[year][month][day] || defaultData;
              //Acumulate data for that day
            processedTransactions[year][month][day].count++; 

        }  
    });
    return processedTransactions;
}
```

But now it doesn't work... The object it returns goes infinite, like this:

```
{
  '2019': {
    '7': {
      '7':{
        '7':{
          '7':{
             '7':{
                  ...
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Here's an interesting read for you on value vs reference in js:
https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has to do with the fact that variables referencing javascript objects are referencing a memory address rather than the object itself. This is the same reason that you can change the contents of an object that is stored as a constant, whereas you cannot change the value of a Number, String, etc stored as a constant. If you make any changes to what was originally referenced as the `defaultData` in the `processedTransactions` object it will make those changes to all of the `defaultData` objects inserted into `processedTransactions`, because they're all actually the same. That is they are all just referencing the same place in memory.

You could remove any statements like: `processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || defaultData;` and opt for a simple function like

```javascript
const emptyCountObjectFactory = () => {
    return {count: 0};
}
```

And subsequently change all references like `processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || defaultData;` to
`processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || emptyCountObjectFactory();`